# Learning a representation from a set of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning

I'm currently dealing with the following problem: I have a set of feature vectors (real-valued) describing different instances of a common entity (such as an object or an event). Using these vectors, I would like to learn a common representation (a vector) for this entity (be it in the same vector space or a reduced one).

The most straightforward solution would be to use an arithmetic average. However, I was wondering if you could suggest some other solutions too?

Comment: this probably should be moved to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the end goal of your task? Once you get your common representation, how will it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also look at Principle Component Analysis (just google) and [Sparse Dictionary Learning](http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what the requirements are for the 'common representation' but you could have a look at [Vector quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_quantization).